# ASP.NET Configuration Folder Security Login Issues

Tags: asp.net

- I used the ASP.NET Configuration wizard to set up a web user.
- I then denied access to anonymous users on a folder.
- This works locally.
- However, when I upload my webiste to my hosting provider, when checking the login it says that it can't "access the SQL Server 2005".
- I notice that the wizard created the database files:

  App_Data/ASPNETDB.MDF
  App_Data/aspnetdb_log.ldf
- So I assume the rights are not correct on the website access these files.
- In my FileZilla FTP client, I changed the App_Data directory and all files in it to 777 but it still gets the "can't access" error.

Has anyone had the problem before?

**A N S W E R:**
Thank you Pradeep, I contacted my provider, he said to use the online file manager to set the rights, which worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check with your hosting provider. make sure they have support for sql database drivers. Also ask them about the permission on App_Data folder. One way to check this is - try creating one page which gets data from database and doesn't require authentication. If it works there shouldn't be any problem with database drivers and it has to be a permission issue. Hope this helps.